# not able to set height of UITableView dynamic in objective c

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

i created an iPad application, in which i used searchBar, in searchBar data is coming from database, and  i am storing it in an array called tableData.

After this i am passing this tabledata array to tableView called myTableView, i declared height of table view in didLoad method.

I want height of tableView to be dynamic according to number of elements in table,

here is the code snippet,

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // only show the status bar’s cancel button while in edit mode

    sBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    // flush the previous search content
    [tableData removeAllObjects];
}


- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    sBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    [myTableView setHidden:TRUE];
}


- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [myTableView setHidden:FALSE];
    [tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search
    myTableView.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:4.0 / 255 green:24.0 / 255 blue:41.0 / 255 alpha:1.0];


    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTableView];

    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""]||searchText==nil){
        [myTableView setHidden:TRUE];
        [myTableView reloadData];
        return;
    }
    NSInteger counter = 0;
    for(NSString *name in arr)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(r.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the naames.
            {
                [tableData addObject:name];
            }
        }
        counter++;
        [pool release];
    }
    [myTableView reloadData];
}


- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // if a valid search was entered but the user wanted to cancel, bring back the main list content
    [tableData removeAllObjects];

    @try{
        [myTableView reloadData];
    }
    @catch(NSException *e){
    }
    [sBar resignFirstResponder];
    sBar.text = @"";
}


// called when Search (in our case “Done”) button pressed
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

declaration of myTableView in didLoad:

```
myTableView.frame=CGRectMake(550, 00, 220,400);
```

see screenshot,
in first image data is there but, tableView doesn't increases it's size and in second image only 1 data is there but height is still fix.

[image: screen]
[image: screen]

Comment: I think the title of your question is wrong. From my understanding you want to change the height of the tableView and not the `UISearchBar`'s - am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Atulkumar V. Jain said try this: in the `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` method resize the table's frame as followed:

```
CGRect frame = myTableView.frame;
frame.size.height = MIN(40 * [tableData count], 400); // 400 is the maximum height that the table view can have. You can change it to whatever you like
myTableView.frame = frame;
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` method change the height of the tableview according to the no of records present the array. As you might be knowing the height of the row, so can change the height of the tableview dynamically using the following line

```
tableview.frame.size.height = ROW_HEIGHT*NO_OF_DATA_IN_ARRAY
```

Hope this will solve ur problem.

Comment: I tried `myTableView.frame.size.height=40*[tableData count];`, but it''s giving me following error `Expression is not assignable`.... Any alternative to this?

Comment: First of all u have to save the old rect in a variable then update the height and reassign the updated CGRect to the tableview.

Comment: Do it like this CGRect rect = tableview.frame; Then change the height of the rect. Then reassign the rect to tableview like this tableview.frame = rect;........ Hope this will solve ur issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
     UITableView delegate method, – (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

inside this you can set the height of row dynamically